Little boy gets hit and killed by car
I remember a scene from a movie. It looked pretty recent, 2013-present (99% sure it came out this year), really new looking. The color scheme is very bright and colorful, not dark in story or lighting.
The scene I remember was of a boy, a toddler under 5 years old, and his father are in their driveway carrying groceries. While the father is headed toward the front door, the child is behind the car carrying a bag of groceries but drops the bag (those brown movie grocery bags). As he's picking up the dropped fruit, the car is backing up, on neutral. The dad realizes the car is backing up and he turns around and yells for his son to move, but it's too late.
This scene is silent/slomo, and told through small snipets throughout the movie.

Sounds like Fundamentals of Caring (2016)

Ben (Paul Rudd) is a retired writer, who lost his son three years ago when Ben left his car in neutral on a climb, and whose wife is trying to divorce him. 

